# Why did the foreign key constraint fail on the column `postId`?

Tags: sql, nestjs, prisma

Why did the foreign key constraint fail on the column: `postId`? How can I fill the prisma studio with the same postId values?

[Faker create table git example](https://github.com/TemaOvchinnikov/example/blob/main/prisma/seed.ts)

[Manual filling git example](https://github.com/TemaOvchinnikov/example/blob/main/prisma/seed.example.ts)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbLuL.png)

```
images: {
          create: [
            {
              imagePuth: faker.image.image(),
              postId: faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 7 }), 
            },
          ],
        },




Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...
Start seeding ...
PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in
Z:\spa\project\server\prisma\seed.ts:18:36

  15 async function main() {
  16   console.log(`Start seeding ...`);
  17   for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
→ 18     const user = await prisma.user.create(
  Foreign key constraint failed on the field: `postId`
    at cb (Z:\spa\project\server\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:38537:17)
    at async main (Z:\spa\project\server\prisma\seed.ts:18:18) {
  code: 'P2003',`enter code here`
  clientVersion: '3.3.0',
  meta: { field_name: 'postId' }
}

An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node prisma/seed.ts
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks5v7.png)

```
images: {
          create: [
            {
              imagePuth: faker.image.image(),
              postId: 1,
            },
          ],
        },


console.log('postId ' + faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 7 }));
console.log(`Created user with id: ${user.id}`);




      Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...
Start seeding ...
postId 7
Created user with id: 1
postId 3`enter code here`
Created user with id: 2
postId 5
Created user with id: 3
postId 7
Created user with id: 4
postId 5
Created user with id: 5
postId 5
Created user with id: 6
postId 7
Created user with id: 7
Seeding finished.

The seed command has been executed.





images: {
          create: [
            {
              imagePuth: faker.image.image(),
              postId: 2,
            },
          ],
        },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AsCS.png)

Thank you I did so
Tasin Ishmam

```
    import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';
//import faker from 'faker';
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const faker = require('faker');

async function main() {
  console.log(`Start seeding ...`);

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        email: faker.internet.email(),
        firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
        lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
        avatar: faker.image.avatar(),
      },
    });

    console.log({ user });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    const post = await prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title: faker.name.title(),
        content: faker.lorem.paragraphs(),
        userId: faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 7 }),
      },
    });

    console.log({ post });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    const image = await prisma.image.create({
      data: {
        imagePuth: faker.image.image(),
        postId: faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 7 }),
        userId: faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 7 }),
      },
    });

    console.log({ image });
  }
  console.log(`Seeding finished.`);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't a `Post` record with a `post.id` (or whatever the primary key is) of 2. It would be possible to verify this if you posted your Prisma Schema and existing  `Post` records (as a screenshot in prisma studio).

Comment: Schema 
 https://github.com/TemaOvchinnikov/example/blob/main/prisma/schema.prisma

Comment: Yeah, I believe the error occurs because the `Post` with the appropriate `id` does not yet exist (So you can't reference that id as a foreign key). Perhaps you can create the `Post` records first, or use the [`connectOrCreate` command](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-or-create-a-record).